# TinyMCE validation error

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for upadating my Front UI.
In the textareas it shows **fieldname** cannot exceed 210 characters. How to extend this range or make it rangeless. In DB table this feild is **text** type.

In my header I have configured tinyMCE like following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({
                    mode : "textareas",
                    theme : "advanced",
                    plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview", 

                    // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
                    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
                    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",      
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                    theme_advanced_resizing : true
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

tinyMCE does not impose any limits on the number of characters a textarea can accept when entering data.

Can you show your html code as well so we can get a better idea of what the problem is?

Comment: I would also check any other application-specific JavaScript that your page is including.

Answer (score 0):

For this you would write some code yourself, but it can be done.
I have implemented something similar. If this would work for you let me know.